# Is there an option to use def inside a function in clojure for a recursive definition?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to create an sqrt function using streams in Clojure. For that, I need to define the stream inside the function and return it. The problem resides in that the stream is defined in terms of itself; therefore, using let is not possible, and using def is bogus because it affects the global scope. Is there any way to simulate using a def inside a function that doesn't affect the global scope?

```clj
(defmacro cons-stream [a b]
  (list 'lazy-seq (list 'cons a (list 'lazy-seq b))))

(defn stream-car [stream] (first stream))

(defn stream-cdr [stream] (rest stream))

(defn stream-map [proc & streams]
  (if (empty? (first streams))
    '()
    (cons-stream (apply proc (map stream-car streams))
                 (apply stream-map proc (map stream-cdr streams)))))

(defn average [a b] (/ (+ a b) 2.0))

(defn sqrt-improve [guess x]
  (average guess (/ x guess)))

(defn sqrt-stream [x]
  (def guesses (cons-stream 1.0
                            (stream-map #(sqrt-improve % x) guesses)))
  guesses)
```

I don't want sqrt-stream to create a global guesses stream.

EDIT

In clojure the let definition is only available when it has been evaluated. So this definition throws an error.

```clj
(defn sqrt-stream [x]
  (let [guesses (cons-stream 1.0
                             (stream-map #(sqrt-improve % x) guesses))]
    guesses))
```

Comment: I don't see how the "therefore, using let is not possible" (when a value is recursively defined) claim is true (so long as you ensure that there's an end condition). Could you go into more detail on what you tried and how it failed?

Comment: (responding to the edit) ...right, but you can use let to bind a promise/fn/other handle on a deferred-execution. As far as I can tell, that's what you're trying to use `def` to do implicitly; better to use syntax that's explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@CharlesDuffy is right. A [`promise`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/promise) can be used here:

```
(defn sqrt-stream [x]
  (let [p (promise)]

    (deliver p (cons-stream 1.0
                            (stream-map #(sqrt-improve % x) @p)))
    @p))
```

This does appear to be an XY problem though. Just use existing constructs (as shown below in my previous answer). Also note, `stream-map` is just the built in `map`, and you can use a syntax quote (`` ` ``) to neaten up `cons-stream`:

```
(defmacro cons-stream [a b]
  `(lazy-seq (cons ~a (lazy-seq ~b)))) ; ~ unquotes a and b

(defn average [a b]
  (/ (+ a b) 2.0))

(defn sqrt-improve [guess x]
  (average guess (/ x guess)))

(defn sqrt-stream [x]
  (let [p (promise)]

    (deliver p (cons-stream 1.0
                            (map #(sqrt-improve % x) @p)))
    @p))
```

---

I suggest using [`iterate`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/iterate) here though. It repeatedly applies a function to an initial value, and returns an infinite lazy list of the results. This has the same effect as your original code, but relies entirely on `core` constructs:

```
(defn average [a b]
  (/ (+ a b) 2.0))

(defn sqrt-improve [guess x]
  (average guess (/ x guess)))

(defn sqrt-stream [n]
  (iterate #(sqrt-improve % n) ; Apply this function over and over again
           1.0)) ; The initial value to iterate over
```

Then, use it like:

```
(->> (sqrt-stream 10)
     (take 10))

=>
(1.0
 5.5
 3.659090909090909
 3.196005081874647
 3.16245562280389
 3.162277665175675
 3.162277660168379
 3.162277660168379
 3.162277660168379
 3.162277660168379)
```

You can get a final answer from this by taking as many results as you want to achieve a desired accuracy, then grabbing the final (`last`) value:

```
(->> (sqrt-stream 10)
     (take 100)
     (last))

=> 3.162277660168379
```

Comment: I'm reading SICP, and using clojure to implement the code there. Your suggestion is right on point for the specific sqrt-stream issue. But, the question is if there is a way to use a def inside a function without messing the global scope, something like the recursive definition that def allows with the local scoping of let. You can see my concern by looking at the code snippets in section 3.5.3 of SICP.

Comment: @SantiagoCabrera Updated from suggestions from CharlesDuffy. I still hold though that you should likely not try to reinvent the wheel here. As shown by the existence of `map`; Clojure already has most of the tools you need built in.

Comment: Thanks, using promise is exactly what I needed. The code here is just for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I have just noticed that @Carciginate appended a solution based on `iterate` to the accepted answer some twelve hours before I posted the one that follows.

---

There is no need to set up special functions to manipulate streams. The [standard sequence functions](https://clojure.org/reference/sequences) are designed to manipulate anything that complies with the sequence interface.

Your definitions

```
(defn stream-car [stream] (first stream))
(defn stream-cdr [stream] (rest stream))
```

... can be more simply expressed as

```
(def stream-car first)
(def stream-cdr rest)
```

In other words,

- `stream-car` is a synonym for `first`
- `stream-cdr` is a synonym for `rest`.

Similarly, your `cons-stream` essentially replicates the old `lazy-cons`, which is now deprecated.

Your `stream-map` function adds nothing to the standard `map`, which is lazy already. it also assumes, wrongly, that only the first sequence may run dry.

Anyway, you don't need `map` here. A better fit is [`iterate`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/iterate), which could be defined as

```
(defn iterate [f x]
  (lazy-seq (cons x (iterate f (f x)))))
```

We can then define your `sqrt-stream` as

```
(defn sqrt-stream [x]
  (iterate
    (fn [guess] (sqrt-improve guess x))
    1.0))
```

For example,

```
=> (take 10 (sqrt-stream 10))
(1.0 5.5 3.659090909090909 3.196005081874647 3.16245562280389 
 3.162277665175675 3.162277660168379 3.162277660168379 
 3.162277660168379 3.162277660168379)
```

There are problems which stretch Clojure's sequence repertoire, but this isn't one of them.

Sorry to seem so negative, but a fair amount of thought has gone into designing Clojure to avoid the replication of sequence functions that some previous Lisps have been prone to.